# How to catch error from UrlFetchApp.fetchAll?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, request, fetch, urlfetch

[`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) speeds up the execution time. But with many requests, often occurs errors (429, 500, 503). In most cases, a second request will solve it. How can I catch them? According [benchmark](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/), `HTTPResponse[]` has a different order than request array. Thus I can't send new request (`UrlFetchApp.fetch`), don't know `url` and `params`.

```
let requests = [
    { url: '', muteHttpExceptions: true }, 
    { url: '', muteHttpExceptions: true }
];
let responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
```

Comment: At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. The fechAll method returns the same order with the order of requests. In Summary section, it says that after it worked by the asynchronous processing, the returned values is reordered by the order of requests. The result of Result section indicates the experimental result that the fetchAll method runs with the asynchronous process using the request to the Web Apps.

Comment: You say `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll speeds up the execution time`, but if you get an 429 error - this means that you perform too many request in a short time. To avoid this you should NOT speed up your execution time.

Comment: @ziganotschka if compare `100 fetch` and `10 fetchAll` - the difference is also significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According benchmark, HTTPResponse[] has a different order than request array.

Im wrong. Summary section gave the next rule:

> After it worked by the asynchronous processing, the returned values is reordered by the order of requests.

In practice my case, it is true.

Thanks [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)